# Merging ifs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I'm working on Datatables and I'm just a jQuery beginner. I want to merge some of the JSON output through the DT render property. I tried this:

```
 function ( data, type, full ) {
 return full["a"] + full["b"] + full["c"] + full["d"];}
```

But this doesn't work, because when there's no C or D in the data row, an "undefined" will appear. So I turned to conditionals that will check before posting the result.

```
function ( data, type, full ) {
      if (full["a"]) {
        return full["a"];}
      else if (full["a"] && full["b"]) {
        return full["a"] + full["b"];}
```

I would then go through some iteration of this until I get all the variables I need — A, B, C, and D. Plus, this doesn't work. Any shortcut?

**Update**: I'm now using the map function, which kind of gives me the result I was looking for, but I'm still looking for some granular control of the variables. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/east1999/0zdjy1yz/).

**Update 2**: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797212/granular-manipulation-of-array-variables-in-datatables) for another iteration of the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to loop over the object

```
var res = [];
for (var o in full) res.push(full[o]);
return res.length==0?"":res.join(",");
```

```js
var full = {"a":"A","c":"C","d":"D"}, res = [];
for (var o in full) res.push(full[o]);
console.log(res.length==0?"":res.join(","));
```

Alternative if no commas needed

```
return (full["a"] || "") +  
       (full["b"] || "") + 
       (full["c"] || "") + 
       (full["d"] || "");
```

jQuery example:

```js
var full = {
    "type": "book",
    "title": "Title",
    "container-title": "", // empty
    "publisher": "Publisher",
    "page": "Pages X to X",
    "volume": "XXX"
  },
  res = [];
$.each(full, function(key, val) {
  if ($.trim(val) != "") res.push(val);
});
console.log(res.length == 0 ? "" : res.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank works like a charm! But —excuse me for adding this— how can I add conditional spaces or commas? I mean, this is bibliographic information. Meaning, a title can have A, C, and D, or sometimes, just C and D.

Comment: I used a variation of this, but defining `var a = full["container-title"]; var b = full["page"]; var c = full["volume"];` because my variables are Publication Title, Page, and Volume. Then I included a, b, c in res. It mostly works but I get some lonely commas when one or two fields are empty.

Comment: I have added `if ($.trim(val) !="") res.push(val);` to skip empty values and spaces

Comment: That was giving me my date _and_ all the data in the JSON row, so I removed it.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Show the JSON and expected output

Comment: See [link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/vawiz) for an example of a JSON file structured like mine. I only need container-title, page, and volume. Your code does the following — the for loop you initially shared works fine but the commas get misplaced when there is an empty/undef. field. The each loop just returns _all_ the data in a record, but the commas are properly distributed.

Comment: I do not get you issue. See my last code with the example from your JSON. If you need to iterate over a complex JSON with nested arrays, the code needs updating. Note I am away from keyboard until tomorrow

Comment: Sorry, as a newbie, I took some time to understand what you were doing, and I also wanted to create a fiddle so I could explain myself. See the update above.

Answer (score 0):

as full is an array, then you can use $.each on it and add the result to a variable only if the current element is not having bad data(undefined, null)

Comment: Full is not an array. It is an object.