# Granular manipulation of array variables in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

You can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/east1999/0zdjy1yz/4/) that I'm looking for a solution that lets me join a couple of JSON fields in the **same** Datatables column. This is the solution I found:

```
 function ( data, type, full ) {
      var a = (full["container-title"]);
      var b = (full["volume"]);
      var c = (full["issue"]);
      var d = (full["page"]);
      var x = ([a, b, c, d]);
      return $.map( x, function ( d, i ) {
      return d;}).join( ', ' );
    }
```

This outputs the values I want, separated by commas. However, I would like to add some html to *each* variable before the output. Say, for instance, I want "volume" to be preceded by "Vol.". But if I try this

`var a = 'Vol.' + (full["volume"]);`

the value is passed as "undefined" and completely unusable. Any other route?

Comment: Please correct your fiddle - you have javascript in the html section and html in the javascript section, and you're not loading any libraries - jQuery and DataTables. Also, you don't have any sample data to illustrate, so nothing runs.  Otherwise, it would be better to embed your code in this question

Comment: I am so sorry, I must've posted the wrong fiddle. I've updated it now.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/east1999/0zdjy1yz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does work, check this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/0zdjy1yz/6/). What you were running into was not being able to find the relevant data for `issue` as it's not in your data, if you do a check before adding it to the array you're laughing:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/vawiz",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "",
        "defaultContent": null,
        "render": function(data, type, full) {
            var x = [];
            if (full["container-title"]) {
                x.push("Title: " + full["container-title"]);
            }
            if (full["volume"]) {
                x.push("Volumns: " + full["volume"]);
            }
            if (full["issue"]) {
                x.push("Issue: " + full["issue"]);
            }
            if (full["page"]) {
                x.push("Page: " + full["page"]);
            }
            return $.map(x, function(d, i) {
                return d;
            }).join(', ');
        }
    }, ],
});
```

Also, your script includes were in the wrong order. :-D

Comment: My friend, this is really something. You may just have solved a lot of datatables problems for me, because I can use this anywhere else to return different values (although I wonder if there's anything a bit shorter?). I kept thinking that if I added html to the var it would "corrupt" the result being returned but I didn't know any different.. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Smaller version: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/0zdjy1yz/7/

Answer (score 0):

This is more elegant if you HAVE to specify which items you want

```
function cFL(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}


"render": function(data, type, full) {
  var x = [], y=["container-title","volume","issue","page"];
  for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++) { 
    if(full[y]) x.push(cFL(y[i])+": "+full[y]);
  }
  return x.length==0?"":x.join(", ");
}
```