# Merge columns in Datatables

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I need to merge two columns in Datatables. I tried to use their suggested method for concatenation in columnRender, but the result is blank (or simply *di*). But even repeating code seems stupid. I simply want to merge the columns' functions, which are the same, but I don't know how:

```
( data, type, full ) => {
    return $.map( data, function ( d, i ) {
    return d.given +' '+ d.family;
    } ).join( ',<br />' );
    }
```

See the full JSFiddle for a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/east1999/zbv4k8yu/3/).

FYI, I've been able to amalgamate other JSON fields using [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802920/3426863), but these fields are different, as they contain arrays, and I cannot find them using `full[]family` or `full.given`. Thank you for your time!

**Edit**: Solved below. I used the answer to load the mapped array2 only if array1 is blank. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/east1999/n94autLq/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "render": (data, type, full) => {
            return $.map(full['author'].concat(full['editor']), function ( d, i ) {
                return d.given +' '+ d.family;
            }).join( ',<br />' );
        },
        "targets": [2] 
    }
]
```

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/zbv4k8yu/5/) for code and demonstration.